# How can I dynamically include external files / user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I am trying to build a C# .NET website that includes files based on DB input.

In PHP, this is simple, where I could do this very easily like this:

```
<?php include('inc/'.$filename);?>
```

Is there something similar to do this in C#? I've been trying to figure this out for a while, and can't find a simple solution. I know I can specify static files like this:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/controls/blah.ascx" TagPrefix="test" TagName="blah" %>
```

... But I can't change the "blah.ascx" dynamically in the code-behind. This would work just fine if I always knew exactly what needed to be included.

Has anyone been able to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution that allows me to include any user control without having to register it in the .aspx page.

```
// Include external files here
// CustomControl variable can equal something like "home.ascx"
UserControl uc = (UserControl)Page.LoadControl("~/pages/" + CustomControl);
// PageCustomControl can be a Panel or PlaceHolder
PageCustomControl.Controls.Add(uc);
```

Based on code from http://forums.asp.net/t/1186225.aspx?Add+Web+User+Control+from+Code+Behind

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add and read from files on the server. Not sure if you want to include existing files or make them on the fly.

Anyway, here's a link that explains how to read from a file on the server.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94223t4d.aspx

Here is a link that explains how to load user controls dynamically.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c0az2h86(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. This would be perfectly valid if I were trying to include static files, however the controls I want to "include" may contain form components and need to have logic parsed by the server. Basically, just like registering a custom user control, but the file location may change based on the form or content I need to dynamically include. Please excuse my terminology if it is rough- I am still fairly novice with C# and have an extensive PHP background.

Comment: Ok. I see. I have added a link for how to dynamically add user controls.